# How to form an URL in LWC Community Page that can carry User Info?

Tags: url, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am forming a web app in lightning Community Experience Builder using LWC, which already has an URL that carries the domain of my org.

Now I want to handover the URL to users along with an Id appended to its end, such that when the user visits the site I can retrieve the Id from URL using JS.
example,

**the original URL**: cs-123.aig.lightning.force.com/form

**User lands with:** cs-123.aig.lightning.force.com/form?userId=123

I must be able to retrieve the userId when the component loads using renderedCallBack or connectedCallBack.

Thanks in advance.

Note:Lightning Navigation Service offered by LWC,doesnt work outside Salesforce,LEX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain JavaScript [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) should be enough. I have something similar on my project and works ok in community, with LWC embedded on the page.

```
connectedCallback() {
    // Try to read the preselected id from URL
    if (window.location.href) {
        try {
            let url = new URL(window.location.href);
            let id = url.searchParams.get('id');
            if (id) {
                this.userId = id;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            if (console) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the resposne. Right now, the URL doesn't involve any parameter. If I append a parameter in the URL Box and press Enter, it redirects me to the page and immediately wipes out the parameters.

I had implemented the exact JS-based solution, which returns null/undefined!
We must also note, that I am presently testing out, the component inside Salesforce, where it lives in the native LEX container. This may be wiping out any parameter that I append, as a consequence of server calls.

Comment: It seems, that I had diagnosed the correct cause. Earlier my solution was supposed to work fine, but it didn't as I was testing it out within Salesforce Ligthning Exp and not the real community Page.

Thank you so much, it was great to have you come down and answer my question!

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes, communities are bit more "normal" with the navigation, in LEX you use navigation and sometimes hacks like `atob` & setting/reading the state from the part after hash... https://www.infallibletechie.com/2021/08/new-button-override-in-salesforce.html